# Why is a Lattice called so?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, lattice-orders

Why is a Lattice called so? In my mind, I relate a Lattice to the picture of Lattice seen usually in chemistry.. like that of a salt, in 3-d space.. or just balls stacked in a plane on top of each other.

And I read the definition of a Lattice as a Poset in which every pair of elements have a least upper bound(join) and greatest lower bound(meet). Although, this definition seems to be related somehow to the above view, I couldn't figure out how. Can you help in seeing the relation between that picture of lattice and the definition?

Or is it just speculative thinking and no relation exists?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples) on Wikipedia?

Comment: [Lattice (meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lattice)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist No, but i have seen these pictures and i thought to myself that yes, these might be how they are related, but then when i observed for a while, i came across the fact that they are Lattice just because they are drawn in 2-d.. If I try to visulalize the same Hasse diagram in 3-d or if i drew the Hasse diagram in 3-d would it be a Lattice?  And then I became unsure regarding whether is this really how they are related ?

Comment: They had to call it something. There doesn't have to be a reason.